# Dropdown menu in mobile and sticky row in desktop view

Tags: html, css, sass

I cant get my desktop menu good...
Started with mobile first, the drop down is working but its hard making a media query thats a row that sticks on the top of the side in desktope view..

```
<nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">MENY</button> <!--Funkar utan type-->
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">SUPPLIERS</a>
        <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
        <a href="#">SMULBOX</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        <a href="#">LOGIN</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Mobile:

```
.dropdown {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
  position: fixed;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, (#FFFDF6),  (#e4cf84));
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #292929;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(241, 241, 193), rgb(178, 179, 139));
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #292929;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #fffdf6;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #d5a848;
}
```

(Works fine)

Desktop media query:

```
.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; //dont know if it does anything
}

.dropbtn {
  display: none; //works
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 1920px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 display: none;
}
```

Cant get it centered or to not dropdown when hover, I want it to be a nice row with links in desktop. No dropdown in desktop view.
I have given up, tried so much different now, dont know where I at so now its just basic again, any suggestions what to add or remove to get it to work?